# How to post review with non-binary and binary file?

Tags: perforce, review-board

When I create Review request with non-binary and binary files using rbt post command, I got the review request generated. But, when I checked the list of files in diffs, I don't see the binary files.

Logically, I see as I added the binary file first time to my workspace, diff wouldn't available for it. But, how to make my reviewers aware that I'm going to submit the binary file? Most importantly, how to make sure the binary file would get available in Jenkins build process (prior to main PerForce Submit)?

I use RBTools 0.7.5 version with PerForce source control.

Answer (score 0):

RBT post doesn't generate diff on new binary added in the workspace.
Hence, the binaries won't get displayed in changesetlist.

One has to create manual review in review board to let other reviewers aware about the binaries planned to push into perforce repo.

Then, we can generate 2nd review using rbt.exe post and send it for code review.